# Geohashing format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geohashing

Is there any specific format for a geohash value? Can I use Geohash.encode(latitude,longitude,precision="8") in ruby script?  What is the maximum value that precision attribute can take? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this library](http://github.com/davetroy/geohash) and the documentation related to it. It's based on C and it says :

> You can encode or decode to an arbitrary level of precision:

- Encode latitude and longitude to a geohash with precision digits
  encode(lat, lon, precision=10)
- Decode a geohash to a latitude and longitude with decimals digits
  decode(geohash, decimals=5)